# Body bounded with three surfaces

Tags: multivariable-calculus, volume

Let B be the body bounded with surfaces:$x^2-y^2=2, x^2-z^2=2, x=2$. Using triple integrals I need to find volume of given body. After projecting this on $OYZ$ plane i get $4$ symmetric parts. And if I take one in the first quadrant, I get bounds $0\le z\le \sqrt{2}, 0\le y\le z$. And I have a problem when it comes to find boundaries for $x$, because we have $3$ surfaces involving $x$.
Should I look which one of the first two is closer to plane $x=2$?

Comment: I found $v=\frac 43$, any idea about solution?

Comment: Nope :(. So when I get 4 "triangles", for the upper and down triangle bounds for x will be $\sqrt{y^2+2}$ and $2$ and for the right and left triangle bounds are $\sqrt{2+z^2}$ and $2$, right?

Comment: Why not : $V=2 \int^2_0 dx \int^{y=\sqrt{x^2-2}}_0 dy\int ^{\sqrt {x^2-2}}_0dz$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the volume bound between the hyperbolic cylinders and the plane, please note both $y$ and $z$ can be expressed in terms of $x$. So here are your bounds.

$-\sqrt{x^2-2} \leq y \leq \sqrt{x^2-2}$

$-\sqrt{x^2-2} \leq z \leq \sqrt{x^2-2}$

$\sqrt2 \leq x \leq 2$

Comment: Riiiight, that is much easier. And the order of integrations is $dy,dz,dx$ or $dz,dy,dx$?

Comment: Yes that is correct. Any other orders than these two would be more complicated.

Comment: Clear. Can't believe I started more difficult way. Thank you!

Comment: Btw if you don't mind asking, which book are you doing these from? I have seen some really good question from you!

Comment: Actually non of them is from one specific book, proffesor gave us script with a lot of different examples.